# Python Flask - image proxy

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm looking for a way to get an image from the web and return it to client (without saving to disk first). Something like that (taken from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/118/)):

```
import requests
from flask import Response, stream_with_context

@files_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_image():  
    req = requests.get('http://www.example.com/image1.png', stream = True)
    return Response(stream_with_context(req.iter_content()), content_type = req.headers['content-type'])
```

Above code is working but its really slow.
Any better way?

Comment: Which part is slow? The `requests.get` or the `return Response`?

Comment: You could try playing with different sizes in `iter_content(chunk_size)`. The default size is `1` which will be really slow. Try `1024` or `2048` instead.

Comment: I changed the chunk_size to 2048 - much better! Thanks! Wanna post that  as answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use redis to cache and proxy your images?
I've written a web app that need to request images from an API server but may get 403 forbidden sometimes, so I get the images from the API server and cache them.

- before:
  client -> API server:may get 403
- now with image proxy:

  - not cached:

    - client -> my server:don't find that
    - my server -> API server:get the image,cache it,send to the client
  - cached:

    - client -> my server:find it and get the image from redis and send back

The difference is:

- before:  client <-> API server
- now: client <-> my server <-> API server

before the client get images **directly** from API server, so may get problems. Now, all the images point to **my server** so I can do more things.

You can also control the time to expire. With the powerful redis, you should be easy.

I'll give you a basic example to help you understand it.

```
from StringIO import StringIO

from flask import send_file, Flask
import requests
import redis

app = Flask(__name__)
redis_server = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379)

@app.route('/img/<server>/<hash_string>')
def image(server, hash_string):
    """Handle image, use redis to cache image."""
    image_url = 'http://www.example.com/blabla.jpg'
    cached = redis_server.get(image_url)
    if cached:
        buffer_image = StringIO(cached)
        buffer_image.seek(0)
    else:
        r = requests.get(image_url)  # you can add UA, referrer, here is an example.
        buffer_image = StringIO(r.content)
        buffer_image.seek(0)
        redis_server.setex(image_url, (60*60*24*7),
                           buffer_image.getvalue())
    return send_file(buffer_image, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

Note that the example above will get the image and cache it only when someone visit it, so may cost some time at the first time. You can fetch the images first by yourself. In my case(I use the way above), I'm fine with it.

The original idea is from [puppy-eyes](https://github.com/cameronmaske/puppy-eyes). Read the source code for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! While this works great, Its to complicated for my task. (I dont have much images and don't need cach)